# Angular - function in ngFor called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a **template**:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let cargo of cargos" class="cont-mat">
...  
 <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let truck of (getTrucksByUserIdAndRules(cargo.id) | async)" formControlName="truckId">{{truck.regNumber}}</mat-checkbox>
```

**Component**

```
getTrucksByUserIdAndRules(cargoId: string) {
    return this.cargosService.getTrucksByUserIdAndRules(this.userId, cargoId).pipe(
      map(response => {
        console.log(response.trucks);
       return response.trucks;
      })
    )
  }
```

and **service**:

```
getTrucksByUserIdAndRules(userId: string, cargoId: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = BACKEND_URL_2 + "getTrucksByUserIdAndRules/" + userId + "/" + cargoId;
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
     map(response => {
      return response;
     })
  );
  }
```

I want to fetch the list of `trucks` in my `template` based on a parameter `cargo.id`. I'm getting `data` from `backend` but the function `getTrucksByUserIdAndRules(cargo.id)` is called multiple times. I know this is not a good practise to use functions inside `template` and any other solution will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `constructor`/`ngOnInit` **component**, load all the data. Note that you should do that in a `resolver`, it will be processed before the component is shown on your browser. You can check out more about `resolver` [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

```
trucksByCargoId: Map<number, Trucks>;

constructor(private yourService: YourService) {
 this.trucksByCargoId = new Map();
 this.cargos.forEach(cargo => {
     // note that I dont recommand making HTTP call inside a loop, you should make only one HTTP call for all the cargo
     this.yourService.getTrucksByUserIdAndRules(cargo.id).subscribe(result => { 
       trucksByCargoId.set(cargo.id, result);
     });
 }
}
```

and in your **HTML** template, retrieve the `trucks` corresponding to the `cargo` with the `Map` you created in your `component`

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let cargo of cargos" class="cont-mat">
...  
 <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let truck of trucksByCargoId.get(cargo.id)" formControlName="truckId">{{truck.regNumber}}</mat-checkbox>
```